# how to run python file in buildspec.yaml using docker-compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, dockerfile, buildspec

I am new to docker world and I've a requirement for an AWS codebuild project where I need to use selenium/hub image and Dockerfile to run some UI tests.
So far what I've done is:

Create docker-compose.yaml file to pull selenium/hub and selenium/node-chrome
Create buildspec.yaml file with docker-compose up --build -d and other commands
A Dockerfile to build the image FROM python:latest and install some dependencies
A small python file to open google.ca using webdriver.Remote

When I build the project in AWS using Code pipeline, I am able to successfully get past initially where it spins up selenium/grid but when I try to run the command "docker run" it errors out as "connection refused"

```
    > [Container] 2022/10/06 19:09:16 Running command docker run
    > mygridimage:ver1
    > ============================= test session starts ============================== platform 
    linux -- Python 3.10.7, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/local/bin/python cachedir:
    > .pytest_cache metadata: {'Python': '3.10.7', 'Platform':
    > 'Linux-4.14.281-212.502.amzn2.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.31',
    > 'Packages': {'pytest': '7.1.2', 'py': '1.11.0', 'pluggy': '1.0.0'},
    > 'Plugins': {'html': '3.1.1', 'metadata': '2.0.2'}} rootdir: /app
    > plugins: html-3.1.1, metadata-2.0.2 collecting ... collected 0 items /
    > 1 error
    > 
    > ==================================== ERRORS ====================================
    > ___________________________ ERROR collecting test.py ___________________________ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:174: in
    > _new_conn
    >     conn = connection.create_connection( /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py:95:
    > in create_connection
    >     raise err /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py:85:
    > in create_connection
    >     sock.connect(sa) E   ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

    These are my files.

buildspec.yaml
--------------

    version: 0.2
    phases:
    pre_build:
    commands:
    - docker-compose up --build -d
    - docker build -t mygridimage:ver1 .
    - docker images
    - docker ps -a
    - docker run mygridimage:ver1
    build:
    commands:
    reports:
    pytest_reports:
    files:
    base-directory: /reports
    file-format: JUNITXML
    artifacts:
    files:
    - "**/*"

Dockerfile
----------

    FROM python:latest
    
    # Set the working directory to /app
    WORKDIR /app
    
    # Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
    ADD . /app
    
    # Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
    #RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
    RUN pip3 install -U -r requirements.txt
    
    # Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
    EXPOSE 80
    
    # Run app.py when the container launches
    ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "pytest", "-v", "-s", "test.py"]

docker-compose.yaml
-------------------

    version: '3.8'
    services:
    selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
    - '4444:4444'
    chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    volumes:
    - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
    depends_on:
    - selenium-hub
    environment:
    - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
    - HUB_PORT=4444

requirements.txt
----------------
    selenium==4.1.3
    pytest==7.1.2
    pytest-html==3.1.1

test.py
-------
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities   
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    URL = "https://www.google.ca"
    driver.get(URL)
    title = driver.title
    print('Title------------>', title)
```

I am not sure what mistake I am doing here...
The error happens in this line from buildspec.yaml

```
    docker run mygridimage:ver1
```

Thanks for your help.